# can not access image from storage folder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

my website can not access images from the storage folder, I have deployed my Laravel project in godday.

this is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule> 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do let us know where is your htaccess rules file and where are your php files etc are present?

Comment: did you run command for make symlink from storage folder?

Comment: htaccess file present in root folder and am using laravel

Comment: no i did not run any command

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan storage:link` and everything should be ok after that.